# losing precision when dividing number greater than 5 digit with 2 in c++

Tags: c++, precision

Following code (in c++) works fine for value less than 6 digit but it start to lose precision when dividing more than 6 digits. Code:

```
double number;
cin>>number;
double result = number / 2.0L;
cout<<result<<endl;
```

Above code gives `61729.5` for `123459` which is correct. But for `1234569` it outputs `617284` which is wrong.
Can anyone please explain what's happening here.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably only the output is rounded. Subtract 610000 and see what happens.

Comment: use [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):  `std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << result << std::endl;` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rf61bv76z).

Comment: Wrong duplicate, it's totally unrelated. Voted to reopen.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @DevSolar Is 32-bit double valid C++ at all?

Comment: @DevSolar I can reproduce the issue on my x86_64 platform which has 64 bit doubles. It's not a floating point precision issue but a display issue.

Comment: @Sebastian: Not all platforms need to be fully conforming. If you don't have a 64-bit FP on your machine, you don't... but it seems I was mistaken anyway, so the question is academic.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is a display issue, increase precision with [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) (the default precision, as established by [`std::basic_ios::init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init), is `6`):

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << result << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rf61bv76z)

Comment: Got this error when submitting my code to codeforces.  Does this affects online judges or my system only. Thanks for answering

Comment: Default of 6 is not system specific, from [`std::basic_ios::init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init).